# Почему эти два куска кода не одно и то же?

Tags: c#, xml

Вот расписанный по операциям код - он работает

```
XElement Image = new XElement("Image");
XAttribute URL = new XAttribute("url", input[i].massive[17]);
Image.Add(URL);
XElement Images = new XElement("Images");
Images.Add(Image);
Ad.Add(Images);
```

А вот, код записанный в одну строчку, он не работает, хотя по идее должен делать то же самое.

```
Ad.Add(new XElement("Images").Add(new XElement("Image").Add(new XAttribute("url", input[i].massive[17]))));
```

Чем отличаются эти два куска кода?

Comment: Тут Вы добавляете image `Images.Add(Image);`, а что вы добавляете тут? ,`new XElement("Images").Add(new XElement("Image").Add(...))`

Comment: я хочу создать контейнер Images, добавить в него Элемент Image с атрибутом url, где input[i].massive[17] содержит в себе текстовую ссылку.

Comment: на выходе получить что то типа такого -<Images>

<Image url="https://i.ibb.co/9Y1pQzh/127-K00127.jpg"/>

</Images>

Comment: В метод `Ad.Add` вы передаёте не `new XElement`, а то что вернёт `Add`

Comment: ну а почему вы решили, что вот эта функция `new XElement("Image").Add(...)` вернет `XElement` ?

Comment: а как переделать что бы правильно возвращала?

Comment: работающую строчку помечу как ответ, и мне наука будет и автор плюшки получит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.add?view=netframework-4.8) имеет тип возврата `void` - то есть он *ничего* не возвращает.

Это *ничего* невозможно вставить куда-либо. Visual Studio, если навести курсор на код, выдаёт сообщение об этом:

> cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'.

В одну строку код можно переписать следующим образом:

```
Ad.Add(new XElement("Images", new XElement("Image", new XAttribute("url", input[i].massive[17]))));
```

Тут используются конструкторы типов `XElement`, `XAttribute`.

Код можно отформатировать так, чтобы было видно иерархию вложенности:

```
Ad.Add(
    new XElement("Images",
        new XElement("Image",
            new XAttribute("url", input[i].massive[17]))));
```

Comment: аааа, тоесть вместо использования метода add, можно засунуть аргументы прямо в конструктор, и компилятор все нормально воспримет? Причем как я понял он сам понимает какой тип обьекта ему подсовывают Элемент или Атрибут, в любом случае добавление происходит правильно...